# chatbot error EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, chatbot

This is my code:

```
for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/Tatheer Hussain/Desktop//ChatBot/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data///english/'):
    data = open('C:/Users/Tatheer Hussain/Desktop//ChatBot/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data///english/'+ files , 'r').readlines()
    bot.train(data)
```

i get this SyntaxError:
EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: No repro. The code you posted does not throw that error.

Comment: for files in os.listdir('C:/Users/Tatheer Hussain/Desktop//ChatBot/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data///english/'):
 data = open('C:/Users/Tatheer Hussain/Desktop/ChatBot/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/'+ files , 'r').readlines()
 bot.train(data)

Comment: I formatted your code for you once, I'm not going to do it again. Comments are not the right place to post that. Your code should be _in the question_.

Comment: Please paste the _complete_ error message in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`\` is the escape character in Python. If you end your string with `\`, it will escape the close quote, so the string is no longer terminated properly.

You should use a raw string by prefixing the open quote with `r`:

```
os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Tatheer Hussain/Desktop//ChatBot/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data///english/')
```

Comment: The OP's code does not have any backslashes. The string in your answer has no backslashes, either. Forward slashes are not special characters and should not be escaped.

Answer (score -2):

The error occurring is because of the backslash.
Backslash is an escape character due to which the quote for the string is escaped. In order to use a backslash in a string make use of a double backslash.
for eg:

```
for file in os.listdir('files'):
    chats=open(r'files\\'+file,'r').readlines()
```